# Why do I get smiley characters while reading a txt file?

Tags: c, fopen

I am trying to continuously read from a text file but I don't know what I am doing wrong here. It keeps printing me some non-printable ascii characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "windows.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n, fd;
    char buff[256];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END) < 0)
    {
        perror("lseek");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            n = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            if (n < 0)
            {
                perror("read");
                break;
            }
            if (n == 0)
            {
                puts(buff);
                Sleep(100);
                continue;
            }
            if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, n) < 0)
            {
                perror("write");
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As for my argument, I pass a filename which contains information like this:

```
foo-12-
```

The output is like this:

[image]

Comment: What is file that you read from ?

Comment: Why are you calling `puts(buff)` when `read` returns `0`?

Comment: @ameyCU I pass the filename as an argument in my other process. Look at example file content I mentioned above i.e. `foo-12-`

Comment: @Barmar That's supposedly where I need to display what is read. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: You displayed what was read with `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
puts(buff);
```

When `read()` returns `0`, it means you've reached the end of the file, so there's nothing to print. You already printed the contents of the file in the previous iterations of the loop, on the line with:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, n)
```

The `puts()` is printing whatever garbage happens to be in `buff`. And since `buff` isn't null-terminated, it may continue printing far past the end of the array, until it finds a null byte.

Get rid of that line.

The reason you're not printing the contents of the file is because at the beginning you do:

```
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)
```

This goes to the end of the file before it tries to read anything. So your program will only display contents that are added to the file **after** you start the program. Because of `sleep(100)`, it will wait 100 seconds before it prints the next chunk.

Comment: Deleting the line `puts(buff)` line only cleared the rubbish which you correctly guessed the source. The problem of 'displaying what is read' is still unanswered.  I also replaced `if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, n))` block and replaced with a `puts` statement still no success.

Comment: You should NOT use `puts()`. That's for printing strings, and `buff` is not a string.

Comment: That was it. Thanks :)

Comment: What were you thinking when you put that in the program? If you wanted to print the file contents, why would you seek to the end first?

Comment: Well, I need to monitor a text file every half a second. That's what I initially came up with. Although you solved the mystery for above question but my code still can't cope with dynamic changes in the txt file i.e. text file gets updated but my code above still showing me the outdated text which is a bugger x-(

Comment: It will only show text that is added to the end of the file. If the file is overwritten, it won't go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is the `lseek()` is placing the file pointer at the end of the file.

Then all subsequent read operations are trying to read past the end of the file.

effectively nothing is read, so the input buffer is unchanged.

Suggest remove the call to `lseek()` so the results of the call to `open()` (which places the file pointer at the beginning of the file) are used.

Then calls to `read()` will properly obtain successive block of the content of the file.

this line: `if (n == 0)` says, if nothing was read.  however a 0 returned from read() means 'end of file'.   so what you really want is `if (n > 0)` which means some bytes were read from the file.

the line: `puts(buff);` will only output characters until a NUL byte is encountered.   However, the `read()` does not terminate the input buffer with a NUL byte, so the call to puts() could output characters past the end of the buff[] array, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Strongly suggest either 1) insert, after the read(), buff[n] = '\0'  or 2) use fgets() to read the lines from the buffer as fgets() does append the buffer with a NUL byte.